# Do Americans use the verb "shove up"?

Tags: american-english, british-english

I saw an American movie in which one of the characters said to the other "scooch over." Do Americans use "scooch over" to mean "shove up"?

Comment: *Shove up* sounds like something obscene.

Comment: Can you give a short explanation of what "shove up" means to you? I'm an American and I don't use this expression, so without looking it up I can't tell you if I use "scootch over" to mean "shove up".

Comment: The following entries from Merriam-Webster and Oxford Dictionaries seem to indicate that they are synonymous expressions: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/shove%20up, https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/scooch

Comment: @tchrist In BrE, the laconic request "Shove up" means "Please make space so that I can sit down." It's a little old-fashioned these days.

Comment: 'Shove up', 'move over', 'budge up' - they're all the same thing, and are used to mean 'I'd like to sit next to you but there isn't room. Move across a little and give me a bit more room'.

Comment: I've heard [scooch up/over](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=scooch+up%2Cscooch+over&year_start=1960&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cscooch%20up%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cscooch%20over%3B%2Cc0) often enough that it no longer sounds particularly weird - but as best I can recall, only ever in an American accent (and that NGram suggests it only really gained traction a few decades ago). I still tend to interpret it as a "blend" of *scoot* (slide along) + *cooch up* (Welsh dialect, cuddle, get closer), but that's probably a spurious "etymology".

Comment: I would never say ***up*** when I meant ***over*** and vice versa.  The verb choice varies by situation.

Comment: In the US, "shove up" is apt to be interpreted to mean "shove it up your ass", an insulting rejection of an offer or suggestion.

Comment: @Mick I don't see what's old fashioned about it. What in your view has replaced it? I still say "shove up" (or possibly "shove over"). Americans don't know about "shove up", they don't ever have a "fry-up" either. And if "shove-up" is obscene, what's a "cock-up"?

Comment: @WS2 A "cock-up" does sound a little off-colored in AmE (ie it sounds very British to Americans)

Answer (score 2):

The word 'shove' is part of the vocabulary, but we phrase the direction differently.
In the phrase ['shove over'](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/shove%20over) Americans take the 'over' as obviously meaning 'to the side'.
In the phrase ['shove up'](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/shove%20up) BrE speakers take the 'up' as obviously meaning 'to the side'.

The fun part of this is that neither 'over' or 'up' have 'to the side' as their primary meaning. Yet we would be completely caught by surprise if we said 'shove over' or 'shove up' and the person we addressed tried literally moving upwards or moving over us.

In regards to the word 'Scooch', 'Skooch', 'Scootch', & 'Skootch': it's very common, but informal way of saying "move your body" (of course the word 'shove' doesn't really lend itself to a formal setting either...). [As with most slang no one really wants to make any authoritative statements on the origin; but it seems clear that it's American and fairly recent.](https://www.etymonline.com/word/scooch)

(This part is completely subjective... I would comfortably use all 3 phrases "scootch over", "scootch forward", or "scootch back". But saying "shove forward" & "shove back" as a direction for a person to move their own body forward or backwards would feel completely alien.)

Comment: In AmE _shove_ is almost always a transitive verb. You can shove [object], but you can't shove [direction]. "Shove off," meaning "leave" is the only counterexample I can think of.

Comment: @MikeHarris well... 2 counterexamples counting "shove over". But in regards to transitivity, I'd say that you're correct for both AmE and BrE. Hover since we've already granted a very informal context for the usage, I think we can agree that expecting to hear "shove yourself over" or "shove yourself off" is a bit unrealistic. The object exists... it is merely implied rather than spoken. For that matter scootch is equally transitive, yet I'd expect to hear the 'yourself' omitted.

Comment: Dear H.R.Rambler, you sir are the sort of noob who would write 'Hover' when he meant 'However'. I've had enough of your ineffable twaddle. Shove off!

Answer (score 0):

To my American ear, "Shove up" would only be used within the context "to shove up against," which connotes being roughly pushed. To ask someone to move over to make more room, such as on a bench, terms that come to my mind include "scootch over," also "move over," "move down," or perhaps with a stranger or in polite company, a simple "excuse me," not "shove up."